# ASP.Net ec2 + s3

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am wondering what's the best way to setup s3 storage for an ec2 instance running windows/IIS/Asp.Net website?

Currently, the website makes web service calls and caches the result to the file system. These cached files will then be used a few times.

Finally an output (movie) file will be generated. This file will need to be stored on S3.

Currently, all I know how to setup is to make a AWS api call to the S3 and store the movie file.

But I heard there's a way to mount S3 as a partition on AWS, but it seems to be linux only?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to archive log files (my primary products are running on EC2). I don't try to map S3 as a volume.

Firstly, use [IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) to create credentials for a separate user that will interact with S3. Limit their permissions to list and write to your output bucket.

Then on your EC2 box, use the AWS command line tools (or one of the SDKs) to simply upload the generated file to S3, using the S3 user credentials from the first step.